# VB.NET PrintDialog Print to file

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, printing, xps

I am using .NET (VB) Graphics to print/preview reports in a pre-defined format (like tax forms), which works just fine.

I would also like to be able to have the ability to accumulate one or more different reports and save them to a file for later conversion to PDF or to use the XPS print driver to print them.

When I check the "print to file" box (for a regular laser printer or the XPS print driver), and click "Print", I do not get an Open File dialog as this article suggests I should ( http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/controls/print.htm ). The operation seems to proceed normally, but I have no idea where to find the file, if in fact one is created.

What am I missing? Can anyone offer an alternative method of accumulating Graphics reports and printing or printing to a file?

TIA for your time.

Comment: Why not use directly a PDF printer? Like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or [BullZip](http://www.bullzip.com/)?

Comment: I would consider a PDF printer. Can they easily be installed (programmatically) on any Windows platform?  Unfortunately both of these links are rather suspect. PDFCreator has gotten very bad reviews for integrating with Babylon Toolbar and, the BullZip link is unavailable.

Comment: For PDFCreator I can't say. Just turned down years ago because was to heavy, for BullZip I use it today with great satisfaction. Tested the link now and works well. 'Installed programmatically' ? I think no, you should include their setup inside yours and lauch during the install of your application or instruct your customers how to install. If you search the web for 'PDF Printer' you will find links to other solutions.

Comment: Ouch... read now about PDFCreator and its toolbar... no way. Please disregard my suggestion about PDFCreator.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will look into BullZip (funny name) and others. Make this suggestion an answer and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the print dialog actually associated with the PrintDocument instance?  Code like this works well:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"c:\temp\test.xps";
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. I am getting an Access Denied error, but at least it seems to be attempting to write to a file. Do you happen to know a work-around for this error?

Comment: Pass another filename, I guess.  Use the appdata path.

Comment: After writing the file and opening, the XPS Viewer reports it is unable to open this document. Is this because it was written using the Graphics object?

Comment: You'll need to start a new question about this, be sure to document it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a PDF Printer? On the net you will find numerous free solutions.
The one I like more is [BullZip](http://www.bullzip.com) but there are other options. If you look for this kind of solution be aware of the dead ends (like adware toolbar or strange licensing terms).
However, this scenario has definite advantages, like you can define a folder as your document base and every time you print, you PDF printer remembers where to create a PDF document.